# AEM 6.x: How do I temporarily/programmatically disable the link checker? (trying to return a JSON with links back to browser)

Tags: aem, sling

So I have a Sling servlet that reads data from another API (let's call it APIX) and APIX gives me the data in JSON format.

When I debugged my code, it seems the response I get from APIX is intact.

When I pass the JSON I got from APIX to browser, I can see that AEM has "link checked" all the links I have in the JSON. I don't want AEM to do anything with my data.

Base on this [Adobe page](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/DisableLinkChecker.html), I added these lines in my code:

```
protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  LinkCheckerSettings linkCheckerSettings = LinkCheckerSettings.fromRequest(request);
  linkCheckerSettings.setIgnoreExternals(true);

  //body of the code here

  response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
  response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");

  printWriter.write(jsonResponse);

  linkCheckerSettings.setIgnoreExternals(false);
}
```

No effect. I can still see these string

```
<img src="/libs/cq/linkchecker/resources/linkcheck_o.gif" alt="invalid link: _blank\\" title="invalid link: _blank\\" border="0">
```

everywhere.

I then tried disabling Linkchecker (via [configMgr/Day CQ Link Checker Transformer](http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr/com.day.cq.rewriter.linkchecker.impl.LinkCheckerTransformerFactory)) and still no effect.

How can I do it?

I called the Slng servlet by typing this URL in my browser: http://localhost:4502/servlets/getpublications?name=john.smith

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

This is a sample of the JSON data I'm getting from APIX (debugging on IntelliJ):

```
"LINKS":[
        "<a x-cq-linkchecker=\"skip\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"http:\/\/www.google23.com\">[Web Link]<\/a>"
        ]
```

This is what I'm getting on the browser (the a tag was somehow replaced by an img tag)

```
"LINKS":[
         "<img src="/libs/cq/linkchecker/resources/linkcheck_o.gif" alt="invalid link: _blank\\" title="invalid link:_blank\\" border="0">                        [Web Link]<\/a>"
        ]
```

I have tried using valid and skip for x-cq-linkchecker but nothing happens.

**Day CQ Link Checker Transformer config screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Can you share a sample link that APIX is returning? Is it a standard `http`/`https` url? Reason I'm asking is - There are links that contain special prefixes like `tel:`, `mailto:` etc, - in which case, you'll have to add them in `Day CQ Link Checker Service` to prevent AEM Link Checker from kicking-in in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think disabling LinkChecker at a global level is recommended. There are a few more ways you can achieve this and place the restriction to only certain use cases -

1. If the link contains special prefixes like `tel:`, `mailto:` etc, - you'll have to add them to `Day CQ Link Checker Service` in `/system/console/configMgr` to disable LinkChecker for these links.
2. Add this parameter `x-cq-linkchecker="valid"` to the `<img>` tag to ensure links are marked as valid in AEM - even though AEM considers them invalid.
3. You can also use `x-cq-linkchecker="skip"` to skip link checker validation for this element.

You might encounter caching issues after updating the above params(2. and 3.), just try deleting contents in `/var/linkchecker` before you start testing.

Comment: isnt't adding `x-cq-linkchecker="valid"` in the sightly code programmatic?

Comment: @SubSul updated original post with JSON data from APIX and what I see on the browser. can you please read? Thanks!

Comment: @mrjayviper looking at the details you've updated, shouldn't the skip param be added to the <img> tag. Essentially, you've got to add the param on the element which gets rendered on the DOM. Also, after adding the params, did you try clearing cached content in /var/linkchecker before testing? I just tried on an independent module and it worked fine.

Comment: @mrjayviper Also, if the link from APIX gets substituted to an attribute which is not listed in `Day CQ Link Checker Transformer` - `Rewrite Elements`, you'll have to make an entry there. Let me know how it goes. Happy to help.

Comment: @SubSul I have no img tag in the JSON data from APIX. It was an a tag but somehow got substituted with a img tag by AEM.

Comment: @SubSul I had a look at Day CQ Link Checker Transformer and I can see a:href listed. This should've taken care of the JSON data from APIX. added screenshot of Day CQ Link Checker Transformer config. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple techniques for handling special url patterns, Refer [here](http://www.wemblog.com/2011/10/how-to-make-sure-that-links-are-always.html). And a very good link checker guide [here](http://www.aemcq5tutorials.com/tutorials/aem-link-checker-comprehensive-guide/).

Technique 1: Code way(Not recommended since not maintainable). Add class `x-cq-linkchecker=”skip”`

Technique 2: Disable link checker. Definitely not recommended in author. Author should witness broken links visible. However it is recommended to disable in publish rather than showing ugly broken link icon.

Technique 3: Add special [url pattern](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/CQ53HowToExcludeURLsFromTheLinkChecker.html). Your link checker should looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The problem is that the links coming through are from thousands of domain names.

Comment: Sure but you ll have a pattern for domain. Special Link Patterns accepts regex patterns.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but only configured "Link Check Override Patterns". I left out "special link patterns". I'm assuming leaving out "special link patterns" would mean it matches any? Thanks again!